# Clicking one div - changing color on three?

Tags: jquery, css

When I click one div I want the div before and after to also change colour. The code works perfectly now, but only changes the colour of the div clicked. I'm really new to using jQuery, so I appreciate any help I can get. Can anybody help?

```
function generateDivs(amount) {
  container.empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    var div = $('<div>');
    div.addClass('box');
    container.append(div);
  }
}

var container = $('#boxes');

$("#addSquareBtn").click(function() {
  var nmbrSquare = $("#nmbrSquare").val();
  generateDivs(nmbrSquare)
});

generateDivs(1);

$(function() {  
    $('#boxes').click(function(event){
    $(event.target).css('background-color', 'plum');

    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide the `HTML` and `CSS`  code also. We can't really help if we don't see the relevant code.

Comment: use `.next()` and `.prev()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prev()` and `next()` like below:-

```
$(function() {  
   $('#boxes').click(function(event){
      $(event.target).css('background-color', 'plum');
      $(this).prev().css('background-color', 'plum');
      $(this).next().css('background-color', 'plum');
   });
});
```

You can use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) too:-

```
$(function() {  
  $(document).on('click','#boxes',function(){
     $(this).css('background-color', 'plum');
     $(this).prev().css('background-color', 'plum');
     $(this).next().css('background-color', 'plum');
  });
});
```

Comment: What if I also want to change the color of every div except the one i doubleclick on?

Comment: `$('div').not(this).css('background-color', 'plum');`

Comment: Okey. So where in the code should I place it? It seems to overwrite some of my code wherever I put it.

Comment: do it something like :-  `$(document).on('dblclick','#boxes',function(){$('div').not(this).css('background-color', 'plum');});`.Please ask new question for more assistance.